# Scaling fastapi and issues

Tags: python, fastapi

Hello I am implementing a microservice endpoint with Fastapi (a get request)
It does two things

****1.Fetches data from a postgres based db - Takes 1 second to fetch the table (I/o operation)**

**2.Runs a operation on that data to return a reponse - Takes 0.5 seconds to run operations on the data fetched above( CPU bound)**

**Total time taken for 1 request = 1.5 seconds****

I am using an async endpoint with a async db connection , so for 10 parallel requests the total time it takes is 5s , shouldnt it be 1.5 seconds as my endpoint is async(also my db operation supports async so thats not the bottleneck).

I am running it with univorn , worker=1
What is causing this extra overhead ? Is it the second operation which is CPU bound executing things sequentially after getting the table asynchronously ?

How can scale the CPU bound part , through increasing the workers(processes).

Answer (score 0):

You only have a single Gunicorn worker, which means that you only have a single thread to work on all the requests. Your database work might be async, but everything that happens as python code within fastapi will only happen sequentially. Increase workers to 5 and see if it makes a difference.

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html

Answer (score 0):

uvicorn main:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=9000 --workers=4

You can start the workers like this.